# How to add ProgressBar while i'm making operations?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hello in my update script in VB.NET, i'm making some stuff, and I want, while all funcs are executed, a progressbar to be displayed? How to do that?
Here is my execution sub:

```
 Private Sub FetchUpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FetchUpdateButton.Click
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
("http://version1.hit.bg/stroiko_install.zip", UpdateClass.WebUpdateZIP)
    Dim AppDir As String = Application.StartupPath()
    MyUpdate.ExtractArchive(UpdateClass.WebUpdateZIP, AppDir)
    File.Delete(UpdateClass.WebUpdateZIP)
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a progress bar from a tool box and manipulate it in your code.

Comment: @Devfly it's very intuitive. Just add the control and experiment some. Then come back with more specific questions if you have them.